# Prove that $|f'(x_0;e)| \leq 1$ for all direction $e \in \mathbb{R}^d$ with $||e||=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function at $x_0$ with $\bigtriangledown f(x_0) = e_1$ with $e_1$ being the first canonical vector of $\mathbb{R}^d$.
Prove that $|f'(x_0;e)| \leq 1$ for all direction $e \in \mathbb{R}^d$ with $||e||=1$

Can anyone explain this one to me? I don't even know where to begin with.

Comment: Do you know know $f'(x_0;e)$ and $\nabla f(x_0)$ are related?

Comment: @MartinR That the gradient can be used to calculate the directional derivative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $f'(x_0;v)$ is a notation that is supposed to mean the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of $v$ at the point $x_0$. Recall that the directional derivative is related to the gradient by
$$\mathrm D_v=v^i\nabla_i$$
And so
$$|(\mathrm D_vf)(x_0)|=|v^i(\nabla_i f)(x_0)|=|v^i(e_1)_i|=|v^i\delta _{1i}|=|v^1|$$
And since $|v|\leq 1$, $|v^1|\leq 1$ as well.